# What is this ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream); function?

Tags: c, linux

When I was looking at the C++ [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function in `<string>`, I accidently run `man getline` in my Ubuntu Terminal I found this function:

```c
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

I know it's totally a different thing from `std::getline`. They just happen to have the same function name.

Neither *APUE* and *The Linux Progamming Interface* mention this function. But it belongs to the standard C library (`#include <stdio.h>`).

I do read the description and it seems that it just a `getline` function storing bytes into a **dynamic buffer/memory**. Nothing special except that.

Could someone tell me what this function is mainly for? What's special about it? Tried Google but got nothing.

Comment: It is a [nonstandard extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) by the GNU C Library.

Comment: @para ya I know that

Comment: Compile with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` to remove gnu droppings from standard lib header files.

Comment: @Rick Then may I suggest reading the actual page: "Since many programs interpret input on the basis of lines, it is convenient to have functions to read a line of text from a stream. Standard C has functions to do this, but they aren’t very safe: null characters and even (for gets) long lines can confuse them. So the GNU C Library provides the nonstandard getline function that makes it easy to read lines reliably."

Comment: @para thank you.. Sorry I missed that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s nothing particularly special about this function. It’s specified by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read a single, newline-delimited line from `stream`, into the buffer whose address is given by `lineptr` and which must be large enough to hold `n` bytes.

The reason `lineptr` and `n` are pointers is that they are used both as input to the function and potentially output from it. If `lineptr` is `NULL` on entry, or `n` indicates that its size is too small to hold the line read from `stream`, then `getline` (re)allocates a buffer and updates `lineptr` and `n` with the corresponding information.

`getline` is easier to use than `fgets` because the latter will stop reading when it reaches the end of the buffer. So if `fgets` tries to read a line longer than the provided buffer, it will return a partial read and the caller will have to read again and connect the multiple parts. In such circumstances, `getline` would reallocate the provided buffer, if any.

As explained in [the GNU C Library documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html),

> Standard C has functions to do this, but they aren’t very safe: null characters and even (for `gets`) long lines can confuse them. So the GNU C Library provides the nonstandard `getline` function that makes it easy to read lines reliably.

(`getline` originated in the GNU C Library and was added to POSIX in the 2008 edition.)

Comment: How is it different from `fgets`? `fgets` can do the same thing. `getline` is kinda like a duplicated thing.

Comment: `fgets` doesn't allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: @KamilCuk But with `fgets` I can allocate dynamic memory beforehand and pass the pointer to `fgets`. How is `getline` better? I mean, `getline` seem to be a redundant function.

Comment: Because it always gets the whole line no matter how long.

Comment: Yes, the advantage of `getline` is that it will always get a complete line, regardless of the size of the provided buffer (or even with no buffer provided).

Comment: @stark You are right.  Thank you guys. But it's interesting that neither *APUE* or *TLPI* mention this function ;(.